# How to disable require-jsdoc eslint in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, eslint

Error : [eslint] Missing JSDoc comment. (require-jsdoc)
I want to disable this error from webpack config so that it will not be displayed on the console.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I used the `.eslintrc.json` file and added this under `rules`

> `"require-jsdoc" : 0`

I don't use webpack. Hope this helps.

Comment: for my version of  "eslint": "7.27.0" this worked like this
    "require-jsdoc" : "off"

Comment: For "eslint": "8.9.0" add "valid-jsdoc": "off", worked for me